# Python - Comparing a Value Against Multiple Variables

Tags: python

Basically, I need help recreating this flow chart in Python. I can't figure out how to get the program to first check a variable against a condition, and then decide what to do. Ultimately it's the multiple if-else statements that are tripping me up.

[image: The flowchart I need help completing]

Comment: What do you have so far? Show us what you did, even if it does not make sense. We can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is a **for** loop.

From looking at your flow chart, I don't know what the for loop should look like though. But this seems to be what you have to do:

```
for <condition>: # You're most likely looking for something in the form "for n in range(<number>)", filling in <number>.
    if int(n)==n: # See flow chart from here on.
        if n%2==0:
            if n%3==0:
                print "%d is a multiple of 6."%n
            else:
                print "%d is even."%n
        else:
            print "%d is odd."%n
    else:
        print "%s is not an integer."%n
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on control flows in python. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

if, elif and else are the keywords you appear to be looking for.